# R ggplot2 with stacked column instead of grouped

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, stacked-bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

I want to plot the data shown below as a grouped bar_plot.

I tried `position = "dodge"` or `position = "dodge2"` but it didn't work. Ι also tried `position = position_dodge()`

It kinda works if i use `geom_bar` instead of `geom_col` and remove the `y=overlap_percent`:

```
p3 <- ggplot(data = comp_coors, aes(x = species_code, fill = mirna_form)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge2") + theme_classic()

p3
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhdU2.png]

but i would like the y_axis to have the `overlap_percent`.

Another attempt which ends in a stacked barplot is:

```
p2 <- ggplot(data = comp_coors, aes(x = species_code, y = overlap_percent, fill = mirna_form)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + theme_classic()

p2
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/erhNo.png]

Finally by using `geom_col`, it returns this which it doesn't make sense, at least to me:

```
p4 <- ggplot(data = comp_coors, aes(x = species_code, y = overlap_percent, fill = mirna_form)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + theme_classic()

p4
```

[image]

The data that i want to plot :

```
comp_coors <- data.table( species = c("aae","cel", "dme","hsa", "mdo"),
mirna_form = c("mature", "precursor"),
overlap_percent = c(100.0, 100.0, 88.0, 95.5, 91.7, 100.0, 96.6, 98.4),
overlapping_attribute = c("ID=MIMAT0014285;Alias=MIMAT0014285", "ID=MI0000043;Alias=MI0000043;Name=cel-mir-72", "ID=MIMAT0000401;Alias=MIMAT0000401;Name=dme-miR-", "ID=MI0000791;Alias=MI0000791;Name=hsa-mir-383", "ID=MI0005331;Alias=MI0005331;Name=mdo-let-7g")
)
```

Comment: Using your data example, the `geom_col` method gives a graph (after renaming `species` with `species_code`) which does make sense to me. What exactly do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `species` as a factor and add `stat = "identity"` like this:

```
ggplot(data = comp_coors, aes(x = factor(species), y = overlap_percent, fill = mirna_form)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + theme_classic() + labs(x = "Species", y = "Overlap percent")
```

Output:

[image]

A grouped barplot with `overlap_percent` on y-axis right.